Azure App Insights connection string null returned in Azure Function
I am using App Insights for an old azure function app (Blob Trigger) that's running on 2.x runtime, a few weeks ago without any change made to code, I am getting an error

Value cannot be null (Parameter 'ConnectionString')

I am using these app settings
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION
AzureWebJobsStorage

and after some digging I found that I am missing AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType app settings in my configuration settings.
If these were required, how could the function be running fine for the past 2 years. Am I missing something here.

Can you share the code which you have tried?

Did you get a chance to look into the below solution.


Value cannot be null (Parameter 'ConnectionString')

This error indicates that a required connection string or configuration setting for your Azure Function app is not provided  correctly.

Make sure the SqlConnectionString is correct without any extra quotes
Add the sqlconnectionstring in environment variables of function app and must be the same name in local and Azure.
Ensure that storage connection string given correctly.

I have created blob trigger function with run stack .NET. I have configured the storage connection string in local.settings.json and call it in code.
When I uploaded the document in container the function got triggered successfully.
Function code:
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Function1))]
    public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("sample/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage1")] Stream stream, string name)
    {
        using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
    }
}

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        // If you want to configure telemetry initializers or modules, do it here
        // services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyCustomTelemetryInitializer>();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "your appinsights conn-string",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage1": "your storage conn-string"
    }
}

Output:

Check the logs below which are getting in application insights.

Application insights connection string and storage connection strings are configured in app settings of function app in portal.
